# AngularJS three out of four validations

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, validation, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to validate password, but i have a problem. For now, I have an input with next validators:

```
<form name="RegisterForm">
    <input type="password" name="password"
                           ng-minlength="8"
                           ng-maxlength="20"
                           space-restricted
                           numbers-required
                           lowercase-required
                           uppercase-required
                           special-characters-required
                           password-validator
                           required>
</form>
```

Here is the sample of lowercase validator:

```
function lowercaseRequired() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'A',
        link: link
    };
}

function link(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
    ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function(value) {
        var validationPattern = /(?=.*[a-z])|^$/,
            isValid = validationPattern.test(value);

        ngModel.$setValidity('lowercaseRequired', isValid);
        return isValid ? value : undefined;

}
```

> How i can handle minimum three out of four validations?

- lowercase
- uppercase
- special characters
- numbers

I thought about big regexp, but it was a bad idea, I think. As a result, I need to get a password that contains : min 8 chars, max 20 chars, doesn't contain whitespaces, and contains minimum three out of four validations.

Comment: this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48635152/regex-for-default-asp-net-core-identity-password/48636105#48636105

Comment: @MJNBelief, thank you!

Comment: @withrp you may benefit from [Reference -Password Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48345922)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer:
`^((?=.*[\d])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^\w\d\s])|(?=.*[\d])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^\w\d\s])|(?=.*[\d])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[^\w\d\s])).{8,20}$`

**[REGEXR](https://regexr.com/3ksdt)**

Where:

- `^` - beginning of line anchor
- `((?=.*[\d])` - check for digits
- `(?=.*[a-z])` - check for lower case
- `(?=.*[A-Z])` - check for upper case
- `|(?=.*[a-z]) (?=.*[A-Z]) (?=.*[^\w\d\s])` - check for special chars
- `|(?=.*[\d]) (?=.*[A-Z]) (?=.*[^\w\d\s])|(?=.*[\d]) (?=.*[a-z]) (?=.*[^\w\d\s]))\S{8,20}` - match any character ('`\S`' expect whitespace) from `8` start char at the end `20` of line anchor